# PHPexcel load an html formatted variable

Tags: phpexcel

i am trying to load an html snippet variable into a spreadsheet.I have differnet sections which may have different dynamic html content. So i cant just convert manually.

```
$dynamic_code_snippet = '<ul><li>item one</li><li>item two</li></ul>';
```

At the moment i am trying this but get errors:

```
if(!empty($dynamic_code_snippet)){
                $excelHTMLReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');
                $snippet = $excelHTMLReader->load($dynamic_code_snippet);
                $snippetWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($snippet,'Excel2007');
                ob_start();
                $snippetWriter->save('php://output');
                $code  = ob_get_clean();
                $table->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1, $code);
                }
```

I get an error:
Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPExcel_Reader_Exception: Could not open in PHPExcel\Reader\Abstract.php on line 196

Do you think its because its a snippet not a full page html document(no `<html><head><body>` tags)?
Can it be done? or do i have to rethink?

Comment: After researching a bit further. I have decided to parse the html before writing to the cell. I was hoping the inbuild logic of the html_reader and writer would convert the string  from html to excel format but cant seem to make that work.

Comment: Note that `load()` loads a file, not a string of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPExcel does provide a helper wizard that can be used to convert basic html markup to Riche Text Objects that can be set as a cell value:

```
$wizard = new PHPExcel_Helper_HTML;
$richText = $wizard->toRichTextObject($html);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1', $richText);
```

However, only some markup tags are actively supported, and ordered/unordered lists aren't included.

If you want to take a look at it, and see how the code actually works, possibly modify it to work with lists, then it's the `HTML.php` file in `/Classes/PHPExcel/Helper`.

Comment: Thanks Mark that worked after i realised i didnt have the latest PHPecel. Thankyou for PHPexcel as well! Note: didnt know where to start with the html.php so i have just run it through a little function to change list tags to paragraph tags`$html = str_replace('<li>',"<p>&middot;",$html);` and works like a dream.